# Load additional data into the view

Tags: php, codeigniter, model-view-controller

I have this PHP code where I am loading a quiz into the view. When I select and submit an answer the view is changed and displays only the correct message or the wrong one.
What I am trying to achieve is when clicking the submit button for the answer, to keep the question and just display under if correct or not.
This is the code that I have:

```
function guess()
{
    $guess = $this->input->get('name',false);
    $personid = $this->input->get('id',false);
    if ($guess === null) {

        $newguess['data'] = $this->Starmodel->getQuestion();
        $this->load->view('starview',$newguess);
    }
    else {
        $res= $this->Starmodel->isCorrectAnswer($personid,$guess);
        $person = $this->load->view('starview', array('iscorrect' => $res,
                                                      'name' => $guess));
         }     
}
```

My main view is starview.php. Can I use divs and target a specific load a view inside the specific div? How can I do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Let say this your **startview** view...

```
//Your question goes here



//Answer part
<?php if($this->input->post()): 
      echo $answer_view_data 
 endif; ?>
```

In your `function guess()`

```
function guess()
{
    $guess = $this->input->get('name',false);
    $personid = $this->input->get('id',false);
    if ($guess === null) {

        $newguess['data'] = $this->Starmodel->getQuestion();
        $this->load->view('starview',$newguess);
    }
    else {
        $res= $this->Starmodel->isCorrectAnswer($personid,$guess);
        $answer_data = 'Sample answer data';
        $person = $this->load->view('starview', array('iscorrect' => $res,
                                                      'name' => $guess, 'answer_data' => $answer_data));
         }     
}
```

Comment: The data is displayed in the same way. I am already displaying the answers **'name' => $guess**